# how to modify print--mail--node--node-type.tpl.php

Tags: 7, nodes

I installed the module https://drupal.org/project/print , drupal 7x , but now we need to get control over each variable on the display node. I mean print out some variables content and other NO, also print it in two columns.
well make a table is not a problem. the PROBLEM is how to get the variable content in order to print out?

I have this code, works, but print all the content by default, in an UGLY way.

I will appreciate ...Any ideas or suggestions.... please sent to me a basic example...

Comment: You should add the code you already have.

Comment: can you please check answer that helps you? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do this by changing display of content type. Just go to the *Manage display* page of the content type you print; at the bottom, expand *Custom display settings* and select *Print*. After saving, you'll see the *Print* tab (next to tabs like *Default* and *Teaser*).

Now you can change the page display settings. You can also change the page style using CSS.